# Spring boot Problem with Multiple DataSource

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to connect to different DataSource(s) with Spring Boot and Spring Data JPA 
I'm using spring boot 2.1.3.RELEASE
I used the following  as a referrence
https://github.com/sivaprasadreddy/beginning-spring-boot-2/tree/master/chapter-08/springboot-multiple-datasources-demo
Here is the code I am using

## DBAppConfig.java #(First data source connection)

```
package com.bmi.config;
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.bmi.app.repository",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "appEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "appTransactionManager"
)
public class DBAppConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.app")
    public DataSourceProperties securityDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }
    @Bean
    public DataSource securityDataSource() {
        DataSourceProperties securityDataSourceProperties = securityDataSourceProperties();
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                    .driverClassName(securityDataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName())
                    .url(securityDataSourceProperties.getUrl())
                    .username(securityDataSourceProperties.getUsername())
                    .password(securityDataSourceProperties.getPassword())
                    .build();
    }
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager securityTransactionManager()
    {
        EntityManagerFactory factory = securityEntityManagerFactory().getObject();
        return new JpaTransactionManager(factory);
    }
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean securityEntityManagerFactory()
    {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(securityDataSource());
        factory.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"com.bmi.app.entity"});
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());

        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto"));
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show-sql", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.show-sql"));
        factory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
        return factory;
    }
}
```

## DBRapportConfig.java #(Second data source)

```
package com.bmi.config;
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.bmi.rapport.repository",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "rapportEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "rapportTransactionManager"
)
public class DBRapportConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.rapport")
    public DataSourceProperties ordersDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource ordersDataSource() {
        DataSourceProperties primaryDataSourceProperties = ordersDataSourceProperties();
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                    .driverClassName(primaryDataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName())
                    .url(primaryDataSourceProperties.getUrl())
                    .username(primaryDataSourceProperties.getUsername())
                    .password(primaryDataSourceProperties.getPassword())
                    .build();
    }
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager ordersTransactionManager()
    {
        EntityManagerFactory factory = ordersEntityManagerFactory().getObject();
        return new JpaTransactionManager(factory);
    }
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean ordersEntityManagerFactory()
    {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(ordersDataSource());
        factory.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"com.bmi.rapport.entity"});
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());

        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto"));
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show-sql", env.getProperty("spring.jpa.show-sql"));
        factory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
       return factory;
    }
}
```

## WebMvcConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{ @Bean
    public OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter securityOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter()
    {
        OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter osivFilter = new OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter();
        osivFilter.setEntityManagerFactoryBeanName("appEntityManagerFactory");
        return osivFilter;
    }
    @Bean
    public OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter ordersOpenEntityManagerInViewFilter()
    {
        OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter osivFilter = new OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter();
        osivFilter.setEntityManagerFactoryBeanName("rapportEntityManagerFactory");
        return osivFilter;
    }}
```

## UtilisateurDetailsService # (where the error says)

```
package com.bmi.service.app;
@Service
public class UtilisateurDetailsService implements UserDetailsService{
    @Autowired
 private UtilisateurRepository utilisateurRepository;
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        Utilisateur utilisateur=utilisateurRepository.findByUtilisateurEmail(email);
        if(utilisateur==null)
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("utilisateur n'exist pas ");
        return new UtilisateurDetails(utilisateur);
    }

}
```

## application.properties

```
datasource.app.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
datasource.app.url=jdbc:sqlserver://pfe2019.hopto.org;databaseName=BMI_APP_DB
datasource.app.username=sa
datasource.app.password=Admin123
datasource.rapport.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
datasource.rapport.url=jdbc:sqlserver://pfe2019.hopto.org;databaseName=MAINTA_TEST
datasource.rapport.username=sa
datasource.rapport.password=Admin123
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

## pom.xml #

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.bmi</groupId>
    <artifactId>BmiReport</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>BmiReport</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
     <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

During start the following error are thrown:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field utilisateurRepository in com.bmi.service.app.UtilisateurDetailsService required a bean named 'appEntityManagerFactory' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'appEntityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
```

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Have a look at the offical documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html

Comment: hello thanks @SimonMartinelli i have seen this documentation before i fixed the error but i got this error now #"could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement"#

Comment: Can you please post the whole stacktrace in the question?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli i sloved my problem  anyway Thank you for your answer!